# iOS - What's called when location services has been accepted?

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I've been roaming around the documentation for [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and don't see anywhere that states what happens when a user accepts location services.  I'm looking for a certain method that would be called similar to when a user denies the use of location services and `didFailWithError` gets called.

I've tried methods such as `didUpdateToLocation` and `didEnterRegion` with breakpoints, but nothing gets called when I hit "ok" for location services.

Thanks,

Comment: did you make sure to `setDelegate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status`
 which is under `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

From there, you can determine the user's status by checking if the status is `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`, `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`, or `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`

Beware, though, this behavior gets a little tricky in iOS4 vs. iOS5. I think it's in iOS4 that this become persistent even when a user deletes the app.

Comment: This still doesn't help me.  When I press 'ok' in my app to use my current location, this `didChangeAuthoriztionStatus` doesn't run.

Comment: Did you set your class as conforming to the CLLocationManagerDelegate? When you instantiated the CLLocationManager, did you set your class as it's delegate?

Comment: I didn't set the delegate in the .m once I did that, it is now being called.  Thanks for your help.